# How can I find the temperature of an integrated graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, temperature, integrated-graphics

I recently got a new laptop with an integrated graphics chip (Intel HD 4400) and was wondering what my temps for that were.  Here is my HWMonitor:

[image: HWMonitor screenshot]

Is the temp the same as the temperatures of the cores?

The mobo info I have:

[image: CPUZ scrreenshot]

Answer (score 1):

An integrated graphics card just means that it is integrated on the motherboard. Based on your HWMonitor, it looks like there is no built-in temperature sensor for your GPU. However, you might be able to estimate it based on the other values. If you can find out where on your motherboard the GPU is in relation to the CPU and the TZ01 and TZ02 temperature sensors, you can probably assume that it is the same temperature as the nearest sensor (within 1 or 2 degrees C).

So to answer your question "Is the temp the same as the temperatures of the cores?", it depends on the geometry of the board and how far the GPU is from the CPU (since you have no obvious GPU temperature sensor)

Comment: I added a screenshot of the mobo info for CPU-Z.  It doesn't seem to tell me much.  How should I proceed from here?

Comment: How much effort are you willing to put in just to find out the temperature of your GPU?